# How to create folder(if not exists) for crontab logs, and write log to specific folder depending on date?

Tags: bash, logging, cron

I have crontab job running every minute. This cron job logs to

```
/tmp/result_"`date +\%dd_\%mm_\%Y_\%Hh_\%Mmin_\%Ssec`".log
```

How to make the cron job store logs by folders is following way:

1. create folder if not exist for `year` ( named by year,like 2018)
2. in `year` folder create(if not exist) `month` folder (like `march` or month number)
3. in month folder,if not exist create day folder (day number)

   > and then: store log for each minute in specific day folder.

Also for now i have my logs written everyminute to /tmp/*, i have many log files like this `result_04d_03m_2018_20h_39min_01sec.log` 
How parse all this files and depending on its names create,  for each year/each month/ each day/ folders and move specific logs to its folder?

Comment: Let your cron job create it's log with the pattern you have.  Then write another script that runs once in a while (like you want, hourly, daily, ..., via crontab again!) to sort the logs.  What you do is you read the log file name, extract the year-month-day values, create the directory as required, move the file to it.  Get started, post your code here, then we can help.  Have fun!

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot, we will help, but not write the whole thing for you.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 3):

I am under the assumption that the log file is created using redirections. So I would suggest the following approach:

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *     command to be executed 
  *  *  *  *  *     mkdir -p `date "+/logdir/\%Y/\%m/\%d"` && command > `date +/logdir/\%Y/\%m/\%d/result_\%dd_\%mm_\%Y_\%Hh_\%Mmin_\%Ssec` 2>&1
```

The command `mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3` will create every directory and subdirectory needed. In this case it will be `/logdir/YYYY/MM/DD`